# How Do I Upgrade From Magento 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 (and what are the related problems?)

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.2.4, ce-1.9.3.0

I've got several separate Magento installations using version 1.9.2.4

I need to update to 1.9.3. What is the 'official' method of updating? And what are the alternative methods, if any?

I normally update my versions of Magento using the update function in Plesk, but I don't think it supports Magento 1 any more (although I'm not 100% sure of this!)

If needed, I have access to my server via FTP, and I'm able to download Magento 1.9.3 from [Magento Tech Resources](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.46567970.423296821.1471248266#download1931) but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with it once I've downloaded it.

Also, what problems have been found after updating to 1.9.3?

Due to extensions I use not being available (yet), I am NOT looking to upgrade or migrate to Magento 2.0 at this time. I just need to know about upgrading to 1.9.3.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Going from one version of 1.x to another is a whole different beast than going from 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: When? Beste method? All primarily opinion based questions IMO

Comment: @7ochem Surely the whole point of StackExchange is to ask for expert opinions!

Comment: StackExchange is a Q&A where questions should be specific so there will be one or two best straight answers popping up. Asking opinion-based questions is generally off-topic because it opens up to a flood of answers of everyone sharing his/her opinion on the matter. At the end, the question is still not answered straight forward. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252854/1306684 or offical don't ask: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @7ochem One person's fact is another person's opinion, or to put it another way "what is truth?". The purpose of my post on here was to get general advice and information regarding upgrading to 1.9.3. At the moment, I'm totally without a clue. All I know is where the zip file is. I don't know what to do with it, or whether it's a good idea to install it or not. Can you advise?

Comment: Ok, you are going into the right direction now. You have a zip file, and what now... This is already more specific. Please reword your question and add this information. Please add how you have access to your server (FTP, SSH, etc...) and add all other relevant context

Comment: OK, I'll update the question...